# Confused with the python results after using some function

Tags: python

I have some problem here. Please look at my code and I don't know what's wrong in the code. It is simple but the results are confusing me. I attached the code below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def S(xc):
    N=len(xc)
    r=0.0
    s=0.0

    # calculation quartile
    for m in range(0,N-1):
        for n in range(m+1,N):
            if (xc[m] > xc[n]):
                q=xc[m]
                xc[m]=xc[n]
                xc[n]=q

    if (N % 4 < 2):
        q=(xc[N-N/4-1] + xc[N-N/4])*0.5-(xc[N/4-1]+xc[N/4])*0.5
    else:
        q=xc[N-N/4-1]-xc[N/4]

    #calculation standard deviation

    for m in range(0,N):
        r+=xc[m]
        s+=xc[m]*xc[m]
    r=np.sqrt(s/N-(r/N)*(r/N))

    #calculation
    if (q<r):
        s=q
    else:
        s=r
    hasil=0.9*(s/1.34)*pow(N,-0.2)
    return hasil

fc=0.3
fm=0.02
mu=1
Nsim=10


bb=[]
for nn in range(0,Nsim):
    bb.append((1+(mu*np.cos(2*np.pi*fm*nn)))*np.cos(2*np.pi*fc*nn))

print bb
print S(bb)
print bb
```

The code works while I just delete the function of "S" in the main function, however, after the "S" function, the data on variable "bb" was different even though I just print the same variable. I don't understand what happened.

I appreciate your help. Thanks a lot

Alvin

Comment: Not sure why are you so surprised, after all you're assigning values into the array in this function, such as `xc[n]=q`...

Answer (score 1):

Calling `S(bb)` changes the contents of `bb` through statements like `xc[m]=xc[n]`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the (un)expected behaviour when working with *mutable types* in Python. In your case, passing in a mutable type `bb`, which is a list, to the function `S`.

You pass `bb` into `S()` with the variable name `xc` and within S, you've got the lines `xc[m]=xc[n]` and `xc[n]=q`. This changes the list `xc`, which is the same list `bb` points to.

Simpler example of what is happening:

```
>>> def funny(some_list):
...     for i in range(len(some_list)):  # terrible way to iterate over a list
...         some_list[i] = some_list[i] * 2  # assigning back to the list
...
>>>
>>> alist = [1, 2, 3]
>>>
>>> funny(alist)
>>> alist
[2, 4, 6]
>>>
```

`alist` got changed after calling `funny()` because of the assignment to the list which I passed in.

If you don't want that behaviour, either pass in a copy of the list as `S(bb[:])` or create a new list inside `S` by creating a copy of `xc`.

Answer (score 0):

`bb` is a list, and lists are mutable.

Even though `S()` refers to its argument by a different name, `xc`, ultimately it refers to the same object.  When `S()` executes statements such as `xc[n]=q`, the underlying list object is altered.